# (Java/Spring) What is ".from()"? (Used with Example)

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa

On Baeldung.com there is a tutorial "Spring Data JPA Query by Example"

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-query-by-example

They create an @Entity-annotated class Passenger:

```
@Entity
class Passenger { /*...*/}
```

Later they do a demonstration using the Example-class, and a ".from"-mehtod on the "Passenger"-class:

```
Example<Passenger> example = Example.of(Passenger.from("Fred", "Bloggs", null));
```

Where does this "from"-mehtod come from? It's not declared in Passenger-class, nor do I find information that it is part of the Object-class.

It seems to me that I do miss an important Java-feature?

How don't find any information on this in this tutorial, so I feel a little lost...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here `Passenger.from` is a static method of `Passenger` class.
Static methods are the methods in Java that can be called without creating an object of class. They are referenced by the class name itself or reference to the Object of that class.
Like -

```
 public static Passenger from(String firstName, String lastName) {
        return new Passenger(firstName, lastName);
 }
```

You can find `Passenger` class details used in tutorial [here](https://github.com/eugenp/tutorials/blob/06cb2e5351bc40428ace7844b6384688f8065d8b/persistence-modules/spring-data-jpa-2/src/main/java/com/baeldung/entity/Passenger.java)

Comment: thx, so the Example was not complete in this sense ;) ... is "from()" a standard pattern?

Comment: There is a line in `Passnger` class `// constructor, getters etc.` and they added github project link of details code in tutorial.

Comment: ok, so it's a standard pattern? using "from()" as a constructor?

Comment: It's not a constructor, and it is not a standard pattern like that you can use different name also. Static methods are designed with aim to be shared among all Objects created from the same class. Here `.from()` used as creating new instance of class  calling constructor inside.